# Reducer Typescript Error: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When the reducer return Union Type, the following error occurred.

[image]

It's okay if I return state, but why do I get error??

```
interface InputStates {
  value: string;
  isTouched: boolean;
}
interface Action {
  type: string;
}

const initialState = {
  value: '',
  isTouched: false
}

function inputReducer(state:InputStates, action:Action):InputStates|Error{
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_INPUT':
      return {
        value: state.value,
        isTouched: true
      }
    default:
      return new Error('Unhandled Action')
  }
}

function useInput() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, initialState);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you return `ImputStates | Error` from the reducer, that is the actual type of your state. You'll need to adjust your reducer to acknowledge this. Here's one example of how to address it:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmAlNATJBjNKAXzgDMoIQ4ByKNAQzxmoG4AoN4AOxkNMbRwAklzBIYAZRj1eKRGzhwAbvQA2SNAC44KGFG4BzdouAoAKhHwALHNoBGECKoZd2RDt15R+BOAEEmYAgueUUYAE8wLR09QzcOPGDdOG5gGGA1KRlokTFJaVk4AF5Q5TUNbWpqABoFFPNLPBtsbX5VdFqidjZSJC5A4JTRcSxcAig4AApdbO1c8SzCgB84AFEoCihquEZ04O0Ava4ASjnh-Oy5FfXN0uBSKZneIZn+tAgHm+hjuDoYJCgISeaG6ihQAHc0k0prsglwAHQRKI-BB1RR4ejoGgAYQAEn4AHIAcVWAH0hASAAoAVTM1E0aMUvzQ-0BpSZTJU6miwPhXI0tQ5HNMFmstjgegFjMUXUZ2DQ-CQqhgDKFzNZIS4aHBaw20Em1GpXCs9C42Gc2H8Ay41GOxjg7ncPT61rgqDQ8xgkxRdUSXGSAG1gdtsKYwDImgBdYpu9CjfCESbcPLx8bbVLpTIFNB2thEIA)

```ts
function inputReducer (state: InputStates | Error, action: Action): InputStates | Error {
  if (state instanceof Error) return state;

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_INPUT':
      return {
        value: state.value,
        isTouched: true,
      };
    default:
      return new Error('Unhandled Action');
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can move the potential error onto a property of the state instead:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmAlNATJBjNKAXzgDMoIQ4ByKNAQzxmoG4AoN4AOxkNMbRwAklzBIYAZRj1eKRGzhxCFKAH4AXHACiUFe0UA3egBskaTShhRuAc31xgKACoR8ACxyaARhAjGGXOxEHNy8UPwEcACCTMAQXPKKMACeYOZwltZcdmzBbHjxlg5cwDDAJlIy6SJiktKycAC8iXBGpunU1AA0Cg7Ornge2Jr8xug9ROxspEhcsfHFtVi4BFBwABSWVZo14pWyXXCMZfGaMSdcAJQ7onv1aHIIvSgA7qWDG8dxXAB0KWmXFqKPD0dA0ADCAAkogA5ADiWgA+kIYQAFACqTmo6l6ikUdBgSCgCSeeLJrRMZgs9x+bTMPXJeMcLncnjgVnpuLxky52DQ-CQxhgOMZBKJJJ+kq2vEOymgmi4aBe2l00HW1HRXDc9C42H82Gi8y41EuPMUwTyMzmFzgqDQuxg60BpLgBS4RQA2tK0IdsI4wDJBgBdJq29DLfCEdbcJY4SNQQ7cUrlYz7NCXIJAA)

```ts
interface InputStates {
  error?: Error;
  value: string;
  isTouched: boolean;
}

// ...

function inputReducer (state: InputStates, action: Action): InputStates {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_INPUT':
      return {
        value: state.value,
        isTouched: true,
      };
    default:
      return {...state, error: new Error('Unhandled Action')};
  }
}
```

which is probably a more common approach and easier to work with in your components which subscribe to the state.